# What syntax is causing an error "SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop condition"?

Tags: javascript, html, json

```
$.getJSON("blogData.json", function(data) {

if((Object.keys(data).length) < 2){
    for(var i=0; i =Object.keys(data).length){
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h3>" + data[data.length-i].title + "</h3>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h4>" + data[data.length-i].desc + "</h4>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h4>" + data[data.length-i].author + "</h4>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<p>" + data[data.length-i].post + "</p>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<br>");
    }
}
else{
    for(var x=0; x = 2; x++; ){
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h3>" + data[data.length-i].title+ "</h3>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h4>" + data[data.length-i].desc + "</h4>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h4>" + data[data.length-i].author + "</h4>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<p>" + data[data.length-i].post + "</p>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<br>");

}
}

});
```

I am unable to work out why this is causing an issue in my website? I would like the JSON array to be displayed but only the 2 most recent records added to the array? Anybody able to advise on this issue?

Comment: Hope you realize your for loops have inaccurate stopping conditions.

Comment: Can you explain how please?

Comment: `for(var x=0; x = 2; x++; ){`will create an endless loop because `x=2` is assignment so it always returns true. You probably meant to write `x==2`

Comment: When dynamically building DOM try to append everything in memory first and only in the end append to `$("#blogPosts")` or you might freeze the page until the code is done. Unless you want streamlined display of data in that case ensure to add a `setTimeout` periodically during the loop to allow the UI to refresh and not freeze.

Comment: `for(var i=0; i =Object.keys(data).length)` you have missed a semi-column in this for loop, and you have an infinite loop due to the assignment instead of conditon

Comment: @R31D Both your `for` loops are invalid. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for for details on how to write  a valid `for` loop. You can use a free IDE to write your code as syntax errors will get highlighted right away. Online IDEs like [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit) can also help there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment i in the upper loop:

```
for(var i=0; i =Object.keys(data).length; i++){ // increment i
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h3>" + data[data.length-i].title + "</h3>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h4>" + data[data.length-i].desc + "</h4>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<h4>" + data[data.length-i].author + "</h4>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<p>" + data[data.length-i].post + "</p>");
    $("#blogPosts").append("<br>");
}
```

You can find the documentation for JavaScript for loops at [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: Thank you for this.  Why "SyntaxError: missing ) after for-loop control" shows also? This applies to the second loop using x

Comment: Try to remove the trailing semicolon ; If all works for you, don't forget to upvote and accept my answer ;-)